# Express Route Not Called Node JS

Tags: node.js, api, express, routes

I have an Express API, which was working fine in local environment but not working on server

index.js

```
     var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var version = "v1.0"
//inside local catalogues is present
console.log("File1")
var uristring =
    process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
    'mongodb://localhost/local';

// The http server will listen to an appropriate port, or default to
// port 5000.
var theport = process.env.PORT || 5000;
console.log("File2") 

// Makes connection asynchronously.  Mongoose will queue up database
// operations and release them when the connection is complete.
// mongoose.connect(uristring, function (err, res) {
//     if (err) {
//         console.log('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
//     } else {
//         console.log('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
//     }
// });
mongoose.connect(uristring);

//Schema is not mandatory for retrieving data
var dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product: {
        category: String,
        quantity: String,
        name: String,
        price: String,
        brand: String,
        image: String,
        link: String
    }
});

console.log("File3") 

router.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
console.log("Inside JP")
    //Request URL http://localhost:3000/v1.0/?category=Pantry -> Get Category from Request
    category = req.param("category")

    //Provide the name for model ,ie collection name ->catalogue/catalogues
    var product = mongoose.model('catalogues', dataSchema);

    //Find Everything, For debugging to check if data is flowing correctly
    // product.find({}, function(err, products) {
    //     var userMap = {};
    //     products.forEach(function(product) {
    //        console.log(product)
    //     });
    // });

    //Filtering of Products
    product.find({'category': category}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error occured in the database');
            res.json({})
        }
        //Outputs the Data as JSON
        res.json(docs)
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Console logs File1, File2 and File3 are getting printed but when I make a call to the URL it is throwing 404 error.

the version of node js on the server is 6.10 and the version used for development is 8.9 
is there any way to debug, I'm not able to find the root cause of this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
router.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
. . .
```

Comment: Why should they try it? What does this do? Please edit your answer to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with .htaccess, there should be a .htaccess file inside www folder with the port of the app

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3199/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3199/$1 [P,L]
```